# MVC routing w/ AngularJS model binding how to get parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

My app uses MVC for very simple routing.  I have controllers that serve up a View and that's all they do (no code in the MVC controllers).  I want each page to act as mini-SPA's.  So each View starts with a ng-controller directive.  Within the angular controller I interact with WebAPI to load the model and handle other client-side behavior.  When I go to a page such as /product/3 I want the angularJS controller to know that I want product Id 3.  However, since I'm not using angularJS for routing, I cannot use $routeParams or $stateParams.  I thought about binding to a simple IdViewModel that contains only the Id populated from the MVC controller.  However, in the angularJS controller it seems this is always undefined, so the model-binding works the other way.

```
@model TripPayWeb.SPA.ViewModel.IdViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product Details";
}

<div ng-controller="productDetailsCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" ng-data="id" value="@Model.Id" />
</div>
```

What's the best way to go about getting the ID so I can load my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the angularjs controller, this can be used to get the last piece of the URL.

```
    var url = $window.location.href;
    var bits = url.split('/');
    var id = bits[bits.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar (check out my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051586/angularjs-with-mvc-6/)).  I also didn't want to use controllers and views to serve up static pages.  Therefore, as you can see from my answer, I've created my own ASP.NET 5 middleware to use for Angular.

The middleware is available via Nuget.  Also, you can check out information on the middleware at GitHub for how to use it: https://github.com/a11smiles/AngularMiddleware