# AngularJS with MVC 6

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, dnx

This is an **MVC 6/WebApi** application.  I'm attempting to use WebApi on the backend with AngularJS on the frontend.

I have two static files:  index.html and login.html
(There will eventually be more static files.)

My Angular app is contained in the index.html while views (such as /login) are loaded from static files (i.e. login.html).

If I go to my root URL, index.html is loaded just fine.  However, if I go to /login, I receive a 404 page not found.

Now, let it be said, I **DO NOT** want to bog down my application with a bunch of controllers and views as it's unnecessary to simply serve static files.  That's overkill.

I have my routes setup to serve API calls (i.e. ~/api/whatever).  How I get MVC 6 to ignore all other routes?

FYI, it also appears that *MapPageRoute* is deprecated in MVC 6?

**EDIT:**
One thing I've done to actually get it working is add my own middleware to intercept the request.  The code below is added after all of my default middleware in the *Configure* method:

```
app.Use(next => async context =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
        await next.Invoke(context);
    else
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("index.html"));
});
```

This seems a bit much and it's just a hack. All it does is allows any request that begins with "/api" to go through (which is then picked up by the MVC middleware), but any other call is served with the contents of the *index.html*.  So, if my requested URL is "/login", the *index.html* file is served, *then* Angular looks at the route and loads the *login.html* file into view.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What routing are you using? Internal or ui-router?

Comment: i'm using angular's ui-router.  Also, recheck the question...I've added a hack that does work, but looking for alternatives.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: for what it's worth, what you described as "seeming like a hack" isn't, it's exactly how Html5 Push State routing is handled, on nearly every framework.

Comment: @Claies I mention it as a hack because in prior versions of MVC there was an extension method MapPageRoute where we could use the built-in functionality of MVC to map all requests to _index.html_.  Unfortunately, that method is no longer available in MVC 6.  It seems like a hack, because I would have thought Microsoft (with its push for Angular) would make some type of mechanism to support this instead of forcing us to use controllers and actions.

Comment: @Claies also, thanks for the link, but the new hosting model (just released last month) treats things a little differently - that's why I'm having an issue.  Basically, what I have above is a version of the *ASP.Net C# Rewrites* in the link you provided, but works with Microsoft's new hosting model by working directly in the request pipeline.  Again, it would be much nicer if Microsoft had made this a little more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so since something didn't exist in the MVC 6/ASP.NET 5 framework, I've created my own middleware that provides a lot more flexibility.  It has been added to GitHub and is available through NuGet.

The project page is: https://github.com/a11smiles/AngularMiddleware

Answer (score 0):

I was able do what you are asking [here](https://github.com/mgolois/DivineChMS). Basically, I added a catch all route to my index action:

[Route("{*path}")]

meaning if no MVC action does not exist, call my Index action and angular routing will take from there

Comment: thanks for the response, but you failed to miss the point...  I don't want to use controllers/views.  This is a pure client-side application that communicates with WebApi.